# How can I select the IP address from the output of the `ip route` command using 'src'

Tags: ruby, linux

If I run below command on terminal it gives IP address value

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP '(?<=src )(\d{1,3}.){4}'
```

But when I run same command with '2>&1' then it returns empty string:

```
output = ''
IO.popen("ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP '(?<=src )(\d{1,3}.){4}' 2>&1", 'r+') do |f|
  output = f.read.strip
end
puts output.inspect
```

Please guide me to understand above scenario. 
What modifications I need to add to get IP address.

Comment: Applied match with regex (?<=src )(\d{1,3}.){4} method on output of command 'ip route get 8.8.8.8'.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do with the redirection. In Ruby, backslashes in strings must be escaped. Just replace `\` with `\\`:

```
output = ''
IO.popen("ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep -oP '(?<=src )(\\d{1,3}.){4}' 2>&1", 'r+') do |f|
  output = f.read.strip
end
puts output.inspect
```